# Expectation of multivariate X multiplied by transpose of X

Tags: expected-value

I am trying to answer the following question:

\begin{aligned}
&\text { Let } \mathbf{V} \text { be a vector random variable with mean vector } E(\mathbf{V})=\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{v}} \text { and covariance matrix }\\
&E\left(\mathbf{V}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{v}}\right)(\mathbf{V}-\boldsymbol{\mu} \mathbf{v})^{\prime}=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{v}} . \text { Show that } E\left(\mathbf{V} \mathbf{V}^{\prime}\right)=\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{v}}+\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{v}} \boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{v}}^{\prime}
\end{aligned}

I have no idea where to start. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Thank you, I have done so!

Comment: I think $E\left(\mathbf{V}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{v}}\right)(\mathbf{V}-\boldsymbol{\mu} \mathbf{v})^{\prime}$ should be $E\left(\mathbf{V}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{v}}\right)(\mathbf{V}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_\mathbf{v})^{\prime}$  That is, the last $\mathbf v$ is supposed to be a subscript, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\Sigma_V&=E(V-\mu_v)(V-\mu_v)'\\&=E(V-\mu_v)(V'-\mu_v')\\
&=E(VV'-\mu_vV'-V\mu_v'+\mu_v\mu_v')\\
&=E(VV')-E(\mu_vV')-E(V\mu_v')+E(\mu_v\mu_v') 
\end{align}$$
by linearity of expectation.

Obviously, $E(\mu_v\mu_v')=\mu_v\mu_v'$, and you're done once you justify
$$E(\mu_vV')=\mu_vE(V')=\mu_v\mu_v'\\
E(V\mu_v')=E(V)\mu_v'=\mu_v\mu_v'$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I am able to do the rest.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark, so that it leaves the unsolved queue.